# App failing to see @2x images

Tags: iphone, uiimage

This is driving me nuts. Been searching for 2 days, and I can't find any real solution or explanation for why this is happening. I know there are threads here on SO, as well as some other places, but they have been no help. I have read the Apple documentation on the matter.

I have normal and @2x images in my app. They are named correctly (edit_image.png, and edit_image@2x.png). They are sized correctly (normal is 60x60, @2x is 120x120). They are both being copied into the app bundle, and when I examine the contents, I can see them both in the root.

I am grabbing the image by calling `[UIImage imageNamed:@"edit_image"]`. It never grabs the 2x image. It only sees the 1x image. However, if I check the scale first, and use this code:

```
if ([[UIScreen mainScreen] scale] == 1) {
    NSLog(@"test");
    editImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"edit_image"];
} else {
    editImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"edit_image@2x"];
}
```

Then it does grab the correct image. I have tried everything. I deleted the high res from the project, cleaned, re-added the high res, cleaned and then built, no dice. I deleted all the images, and re-added them, no dice. I have done everything I can think of. What the hell is going on here?

Comment: Just a hunch have you tried calling it by including the file extension [UIImage imageNamed:@"edit_image.png"]

Comment: Yeah, same result. That's what it was, and during the course of trying to get the `@2x` images picked up, I cut out the file extension. But I didn't have any better luck with it on there.

Comment: I'm assuming you're reproducing this on an iPhone 4 device (not simulator), the only device capable of showing @2x images? I don't see that indicated anywhere

Comment: Yeah, sorry, I thought that was implied.  It's happening on an iPhone 4. But should the iPhone 4 simulator also grab the `@2x` assets?

Comment: It should, but sometimes the Simulator has bugs the device doesn't have, and vice versa.

Comment: Which SDK are you compiling against?

Comment: I'm having the same vexing problem, and I'm using the Simulator 4.1 SDK

Comment: I've compiled against 4.0, 4.0.1, 4.0.2, and 4.1 all with the same result.

Comment: do both images have the same resolution (for example 72dpi), the same color mode, color profile etc. etc.?

Comment: Yep. Both images were created from the same original image, just resized.

Comment: I'm struggling with the exact same issue.  Was a solution ever found?

Answer (score 4):

Are you creating universal application for both iPhone & iPad. If universal app is there then you need to create 3 set of images:

1) edit_image~iPad.png

2) edit_image~iphone.png

3) edit_image@2x~iphone.png

each with the same resolution of 72 pixels/inch. While you need to provide double size for that @2x image which I think you've already done this.

Now, try the below code

```
NSString *filePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"edit_image" ofType:@"png"];
UIImage *image = [[UIImage alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:filePath];
```

> Important: When creating
>   high-resolution versions of your
>   images, place the new versions in the
>   same location in your application
>   bundle as the original.

Source: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/SupportingResolutionIndependence/SupportingResolutionIndependence.html

Comment: No, it's not an universal app. It's iPhone, iPod only. And the high res versions are in the exact same place as the originals.

Comment: OK, then it's not required to append device_modifier(like ~ipad or ~iphone) here. Just remove the build directory of your project. And also do empty caches from XCode menu. Remove all .mode1v3 & .pbxuser files from your .xcodeproj directory. And I would request to try the above code. And let me know whether it works or not. Also, I assume that you're using the latest release of SDK 4.1 & not using GM Seed or BETA versions. It should 100% work then.

Comment: This category of UIImage class would help here I think: https://github.com/nesterow/TouchCustoms/blob/master/Classes/UIImage+UniversalApp.h https://github.com/nesterow/TouchCustoms/blob/master/Classes/UIImage+UniversalApp.m

Answer (score 1):

Two silly mistakes that I've made that can cause this problem:

1. Accidentally naming the small
   versions @2x instead of the large
   ones
2. Having the large versions be
   slightly missized (by one pixel)

Comment: Not making these mistakes. When I explicitly load the @2x versions, I get the right image.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to add the "`@2x`" bit, or have the if-else logic at all. Just use `[UIImage imageNamed:@"edit_image"]`.

Comment: But OP said that didn't cause the `@2x` image to be picked up automatically.

Comment: Exactly. Thats the problem. I know the if-else logic is redundant. But I can't pick up the `@2x` image any other way.

Answer (score 0):

I was suffering from the exact same problem, and finally found a solution (after 2 days of searching).

In my case the name of the @2x image didn't exactly match the normal sized image:  `tileSet.png` and `tileset@2x.png`.

What made this so difficult to discover is that the @2x file ***did*** have the correct name in Finder and in XCode.  I was only able to discover the problem by opening the image in Preview and looking at the Inspector.  I don't know enough about the Mac file system to explain how this happens, but once I renamed the file to gibberish, then renamed it back to `tileSet@2x.png` everything started working as expected.